# Complex nested sequelize loop query with value of higher level

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a very complex query. Before this there are several other queries, I don't want to focus on, because it works.

I want all the Products of a Productcategory, on which there is a claim. Starting from the claim. It is not possible to do a new ".then()" because i need the claim id in the appropriate product.

Thank you for every kind of help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92jKU.png)

This is the code:

```
.then(claims => {
    const uniqClaims = _.uniqBy(claims, 'OnId');
    uniqClaims.forEach(claim => {
      CatProduct.findAll({
        where: {
          ProductCategoryId: claim.OnId,
        },
      }).then(catproducts => {
        const ProductId = _.map(catproducts, product => product.ProductId);

        Product.findAll({
          where: {
            id: ProductId,
          },
        }).then(newProducts => {
          console.log('newProducts');

          const addProducts = newProducts.map(v => v.ClaimId = claim);
          products.push(...addProducts);
        });
      });
    });
    console.log(products);
    return res.status(200).json(products);
  });
```

There is no direct, but a transitive relationship between claim and product., so {where: ClaimId: claimIds} is not possible and unintended.
I want to have the claim id in the newproduct-Object.  Any ideas?

Thank you very much!
Laurens

**UPDATE**
I changed it now to the following:

```
.then(uniqClaims => {
        const claimIds = uniqClaims.map(claim => claim.OnId);
        let products = [];

        claimIds.foreach(claimId => {

          CatProduct.findAll({
              where: {
                  ProductCategoryId: claimId,
              }
          }).then(catproducts => {
            const ProductIds = _.map(catproducts, product => product.ProductId);
            Product.findAll({
              where: {
                id: ProductIds,
              }, raw: true
            }).then(newProducts => {
              const serializedNewProducts = newProducts;
              const newProductsWithClaims = serializedNewProducts.map(v => {
                v.claim = claimId;
                return v;
              });
              products.push(...newProductsWithClaims);
            });
          });
        };
        res.status(200).json(products);
    });
```

"Of course" it doesn't work, because the foreach is not async. How can I make it async. I tried really a lot including recap of Promises, async etc, but it just don't work. Can somebody please write the correct code for this here. I'm really stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simplify your code a bit but haven't try it.

```
.then(claims => {

    // Array of unique claims
    claims = _.uniqBy(claims, 'OnId');

    // claimIds => Array of unique ids
    var claimIds = claims.map(claim => claim.OnId);

    // find all cat products that have one of claimIds
    CatProduct.findAll({
        where: {
            // sequelize will use `in` operator automatically since claimIds is an array
            ProductCategoryId: claimIds,
        }
    }).then(catproducts => {

        // productIds => Array of ids
        var productIds = catproducts.map(product => product.ProductId);

        // find all products that have
        // one of productIds
        Product.findAll({
            where: {
                // sequelize will use `in` operator automatically since productIds is an array
                id: productIds
            },
        }).then(newProducts => {
            console.log('newProducts');
            console.log(newProducts);

            newProducts.forEach(function(product){

                // find a ProductCategoryId
                var categoryId = catproducts.find(function(catproduct){
                    if (catproduct.ProductId === product.id)
                        return catproduct.ProductCategoryId;
                });

                // find claim by ProductCategoryId
                var claim = claims.find(c => c.OnId === categoryId);

                product.claim = claim;
            });

            return res.status(200).json(newProducts);
        });
    });
});
```

### Follow up to UPDATE in question

```
// claimIds.foreach(claimId => {

CatProduct.findAll({
    where: {
        ProductCategoryId: claimIds, // find all products in a single query
    }
}).then(catproducts => {
    const ProductIds = catproducts.map(p => p.ProductId);

    Product.findAll({
        where: {
            id: ProductIds,
        },
        raw: true
    }).then(newProducts => {
        const serializedNewProducts = newProducts;
        const newProductsWithClaims = serializedNewProducts.map(v => {
            //v.claim = claimId;
            // each catproducts's ProductCategoryId is claimId
            v.claim = catproducts.find(c => c.ProductId === v.id).ProductCategoryId;
            return v;
        });
        products.push(...newProductsWithClaims);
    });
});

// });
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

I need in the newProducts Objects: newProducts.claim = claimId. The appropriate claim id isn't available in this block.
This is why i tried to iterate, but it doesn't work

Comment: And there is no direct, but a transitive relationship between claim and product., so {where: ClaimId: claimIds} is not possible. Any ideas?

Comment: I have updated the code have a look. I totally missed that you were assigning in `v => v.ClaimId = claim` i thought it was comparison.

Comment: Hi Molda, i finally got it working (see my new UPDATE), but now I have the problem with the sync forEach. Can you please help me? :)

Comment: Love you Molda :D